# How can i prevent ie8 from loading some javascripts in the head section?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-8

I wonder if there is the possibilaty to load some javascript files only if its not the IE 8 like this:

```
<!--[if NOT IE 8]>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/scripts/slideshow.js"></script>
 <![endif]-->



<!--[if IE 8]>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/scripts/slideshowOnlyForIE8.js"></script>
 <![endif]-->
```

Comment: I wonder too. Maybe I'll go check in [Google](http://google.com)

Comment: rtfm: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @lanzz i was not sure if this also works for javascript files...im so sorry!

Comment: Too bad that it is not possible to go ahead and test if it works...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this ([cited from here](http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/))...

```
<!--[if !IE 8]><!-->
   <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/scripts/slideshow.js"></script>      
<!--<![endif]-->

<!--[if IE 8]>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/scripts/slideshowOnlyForIE8.js"></script>        
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: I think you mixed up the scripts a bit. The first conditional statement (`if !IE8`) is used by *all browsers **except** IE8*. The second (`if (gt IE 8)|(lt IE 8)`) are used by *IE versions less than 8 and greater than 8*.

Comment: Corrected! Nice catch @bfrohs! =)

Comment: It's still not correct. IE8 does not receive *any* JavaScript.

Comment: Well, I just tested it and it works as should in Chrome 19 & 21, FF 12 & 13, IE6, IE8, IE9.  But it __does not work in IE7__. At least not in [IE Tester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage).

Comment: What if you changed if **!IE 8** to **if (lt IE 8)|(gt IE 8)** or **if (!IE 8)|(IE 7)**

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are either limited by a feature that IE8 lacks or taking advantage of an IE8 specific feature.  In this case, the best thing to do is test for that gating feature.

Basically, combine the two scripts into one, and kick it off with a simple if test to see if your feature is available:

```
if(crucialIEFunction()) {
    //run IE8 slideshow code
}
else
{
    //run non IE slideshow code
}
```